# Customer Communities Plus Users Can't See Reports

Tags: community, view

having trouble showing reports to users in a community. Has anyone done this successfully?

*Steps I’ve followed so far:*

1. Created a dev org (also tried all these steps in a trailhead playground to the same results)
2. Created a community in that dev org (used the Customer Account Portal template)
3. Created an Account and a contact looking up to that account
4. Created a custom object (Selected Allow Reporting)
5. Created a lookup to Account on that custom object
6. Created a record for that object looking up to my account created earlier
7. Created a report for that object (1 field in report - name - which user has visibility to) and saved it to a report folder shared with the community users
8. Created a Community user (Customer Community Plus license)
9. Created a Permission Set including these 4 permissions and applied to that community user: ‘Create and Customize Reports’, ‘Edit Reports’, ‘Run Reports’ and ‘Report Builder’
10. Set Access to the custom object to Public Read Only
11. Created a sharing set that allows for the custom object looking up to the Account to be seen by community users whose contact looks up to the same account
12. Added a reports tab in the community so the user can go through that to access reports in the folder shared to them

Then when I log into the community as the user, and try to access the report, I get this message
`The report definition is obsolete. Your administrator has disabled all reports for the custom object, or its relationships have changed.` Though I have just created everything.

When I instead create a custom report type with just the object and create a report with that (Instead of using the report type that Saleforce creates when Allow Reporting is selected on the object) I get this message `You don't have sufficient privileges to perform this operation.`

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well guys, hate to say, after following all of the above steps, the answer was something that should have been more obvious... My user did not have access to view the custom object I created. After adding that to my Permission Set, all was well in the community with the ability to view reports.