# Should "View Report" work in a Digital Experience (AKA Community)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, reporting, lightning-community, analytics

As described here [How to get a standard Salesforce report chart to appear in a Digital Experience (AKA a Community)?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343228/how-to-get-a-standard-salesforce-report-chart-to-appear-in-a-digital-experience) I now have report charts showing in my Digital Experience which is great.

Clicking on a chart displays a modal:

[image: report chart modal screen shot]

but the "View Report" button does nothing except close the modal. And there is no option in the Report Chart component in the builder to remove that button.

I have checked the "Enable report options for external users" setting as described in [Enable Report Options for External Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_enable_report_options.htm&type=5) and re-published. That page does mention a "run report page" but I don't know what that is.

Can this button be made to work in a Digital Experience?

Comment: My suggestion is to check the external user profile under system permissions to see if it has 'run reports', check if the report folder is shared (not only the dashboard), and if the user has access to the underlying SObject. Similar to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257209/customer-communities-plus-users-cant-see-reports). But I have to be honest that I don't remember using this feature.

Comment: Thanks @JefersonChaves; I will double check but the chart comes from the report and shows the same data so it is more likely to relate to how the LWCs work and interact i.e. what the chart one does on the click.